# How can I prove that d$\phi(v_p)=(\phi v)_{\phi p}$

Tags: differential-geometry

If a linear transformation $\phi:V\to W$ is smooth, how can I prove that d$\phi(v_p)=(\phi v)_{\phi p}$ where $v_p$ is the velocity vector at $0$ of the curve $\alpha(t)=p+tv$, i.e, $\alpha'(0)=v_p$

Comment: $(\phi(\alpha(t) - \phi(\alpha(0)) /t = \phi(v)$ since $\phi(tv) = t\phi(v)$ by linearity and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of d$\phi$ and $v_p$, we have that d$\phi(v_p) = \dfrac{d}{dt}\phi(\alpha(t))_{t=0}$ where $\alpha(t) = p + tv$.

By linearity, $$\dfrac{d}{dt}\phi(\alpha(t))_{t=0} = \dfrac{d}{dt}\phi(p + tv)_{t=0} = \dfrac{d}{dt}(\phi p + t \phi v)_{t=0} = \dfrac{d}{dt}\gamma(t)_{t=0}$$

Where $\gamma(t) = \phi p + t \phi v$.

The curve $\gamma(t)$ is such that $\gamma(0) = \phi p$ and $\dfrac{d}{dt}\gamma(t)_{t=0} = \phi v$, so from your notation for $v_p$ you have $\dfrac{d}{dt}\gamma(t)_{t=0} = (\phi v)_{\phi p}$